# My installation USB jumps straight to the desktop and won't allow me to install

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

When I try to upgrade my 10.04 system to 11.10 with my live usb it jumps straight to the desktop and when I click on the "install 11.10" icon nothing happens. I've used the usb on other systems before so I'm guessing it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well when your booting from the usb stick, **at the purple screen** press the **Left arrow key** and it will bring you to a menu that you can just install and other options, instead of boot the desktop...

However, why don't you try upgrading from the *Update Manager*?

Comment: I found that screen but when I clicked on "Install Ubuntu" it took me back to the desktop again. As far as the Update Manager goes I'm in an area with low connectivity so I gotta pay for every mb downloaded (major league sucks).

Answer (score 0):

**KEEP IT SIMPLE**

Create yourself an '**Alternate install CD** (on USB) instead ..

http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download (location near you)

Then your PC wont have the option to boot to desktop, until you have finished install.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that because of the low connectivity issues in my area.

Comment: Although, you can create USB stick anywhere.